# Read/Modify data as hashtable or object

Tags: xml, powershell

I have some data that I read from the registry and wish to modify. Example data looks like this:

```xml
<User Blob>
    <Item>
        <Key>SomeKey</Key>
        <Value>false</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>AnotherKey</Key>
        <Value></Value>
    </Item>
</User Blob>
<Primary Server Blob>
    <Item>
        <Key>Just a key</Key>
        <Value></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>And another key</Key>
        <Value>true</Value>
    </Item>
</Primary Server Blob>
```

I want to be able to change a certain key's value. For example:

```
User Blob.SomeKey = $true
```

I tried to cast the data to XML or to a HashTable but this gives errors.

Comment: Add a root tag around what you have there then you should be able to treat it as xml.

Comment: You also might want to get rid of the spaces in your tags

Comment: @jon Z: yes the spaces seem to be the problem in parsing it...  But the next problem is that there are two root elements?

Comment: That is what adding a root element around the whole thing would fix.

Comment: At this point though, with the amount of string manipulation that you are doing, I think if this were my issue to solve I would just use a string -replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you have XML data which you wish to modify (not just read), and the data is of a small-enough size (to avoid loading massive objects into memory), you would want to use a Document of some kind. Due to its ability to make use of XPath, I would recommend XmlDocument. (XPath makes this sort of problem simple.)

As you rightly point out though, you will need a single XML root. That's easy to solve though - just wrap whatever data you have in another root node.

So here's some code which should do the trick.

```
$data = @"
<UserBlob>
    <Item>
        <Key>SomeKey</Key>
        <Value>false</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>AnotherKey</Key>
        <Value></Value>
    </Item>
</UserBlob>
<PrimaryServerBlob>
    <Item>
        <Key>Just a key</Key>
        <Value></Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Key>And another key</Key>
        <Value>true</Value>
    </Item>
</PrimaryServerBlob>
"@

$wrappedData = "<root>$data</root>"
$doc = new-object Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.LoadXml($wrappedData)
$nodeToChange = $doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/UserBlob/Item[Key='SomeKey']")
if($nodeToChange){
    $nodeToChange.Value = "NEW VALUE"
}
$doc.Save("[PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE]")
```

I've omitted error handling and correct disposal of objects for brevity. I'll leave that up to you. :-)

For more info about XmlDocument, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k.aspx).

**UPDATE**

To remove the additional root document again, just use this to get it as a string.

```
$newWrappedData = $doc.Root.InnerXml
```

Then save the string using a StreamWriter or File.CreateText or something.

Comment: +1 for this example. I think we also need to remove the added root node before saving?

Comment: I added an update to show how to retrieve the xml without the wrapping <root> node.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the code below, note that I uses XMLReader because it can handle the multiple root elements by settings the ConformanceLevel to Fragment. If there are better solutions, please add them as answer...

```
$readerSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$readerSettings.ConformanceLevel = [System.Xml.ConformanceLevel]::Fragment

$reader = [system.Xml.XmlReader]::Create("MyXML.xml", $readerSettings)
while ($reader.Read())
{
    switch ($reader.NodeType)
    {
        "Element"
        {
            $numAttributes = $reader.AttributeCount
            $nodeName = $reader.Name
            "nodeName = {0}" -f $nodeName
            for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $numAttributes ; $i++)
            {
                $attributeValue = $reader.GetAttribute($i)
                "`tattributeValue = {0}" -f $attributeValue
            }

            break
        }
        "Text"
        {
            $xmlNodeText = $reader.Value
            "`txmlNodeText = {0}" -f $xmlNodeText
            break
        }
        "EndElement" 
        {
            $xmlNodeText = [String]::Empty
            break
        }

    default { break }
    }
}
```